# When scaling menu comes behind the div, why?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a menu, en a div with a background color. But when scaling the menu comes behind the div. But it has to push the div down when scaling. The #blauwblok has to be position absolute because somehting else has to come over the div, but not the menu.

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Doelstellingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Producten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Klantcases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="blauwblok">
</div>


#blauwblok{
width: 100%;
background-color: #a2c1e8;
height: 13em;
position: absolute;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwx944qc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I remove the float:right and replaced it with text-align:right.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a higher `z-index` to `nav` element. Keep in mind `z-index` property also needs to set a position:

```css
#blauwblok {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a2c1e8;
  height: 13em;
  position: absolute;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  z-index: 10;/*add z-index*/
  position: relative;/*add position relative*/
}
@media (max-width: 1535px) {
  nav {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "lato" sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Doelstellingen</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Producten</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Klantcases</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="blauwblok">
</div>
```

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Now the menu comes over the div, but it has to push the div down, and menu comes above the div

Comment: Then you don't need `z-index` for this. You can simple remove `float: right` from `nav` element. Take a look [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/uzuvu61b/)

Comment: @melissabos Did my last comment fix your issue?

Comment: no really because menu has to be on the right side of the browser, when i remove the float, the menu is on the left side of the browser

Comment: Then you can add `text-align: right` to `nav`. Take a look [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzuvu61b/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `position: relative` and a greater `z-index` on your nav element:

```css
#blauwblok{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #a2c1e8;
 height: 13em;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
}

nav{
    position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 3em;
 margin-top: 2.5em;
    z-index: 200;
}

@media (max-width: 1535px){
 nav{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
 }
}

li{
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 1em;

}



a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: "lato" sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Doelstellingen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Producten</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Klantcases</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div id="blauwblok">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An absolute element will always break out of your layout and is visible at the top. Except you have a parent `div` with `relative` position.

You can also use `z-index` to get your menu on top of the blue box but I recommend to re-think the use of absolute posiioning.